# Postfix SMTP Relay Configuration Error

Tags: postfix, smtp

For the last day I was searching for solutions for this problem:

My postfix(+dovecot) configuration is fully able to receive e-mails and to serve them via IMAP but it fails at accepting them via SMTP (port 587).

I've already tried adding *example.net* to *relay_domains*, but it failed as it's already in the virtual mailbox domains database.

I've already tried to  add *mail.example.net* to the virtual mailbox domains database.

For set-up I followed [Ars](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/02/16/how-to-run-your-own-e-mail-server-with-your-own-domain-part-1/)[Technica](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/03/06/taking-e-mail-back-part-2-arming-your-server-with-postfix-dovecot/)'s [guide](http://arstechnica.com/business/2014/03/22/taking-e-mail-back-part-3-fortifying-your-box-against-spammers/) on setting up an e-mail server. Maybe one will recognize some elements. Note: I couldn't follow the guide exactly due to the lack of the postfix-dovecot bundle, but I think I've overcome potential issue as I can receive mail.
Note further: Sending to other adresses (like webmaster@example.net) does work.
I can provide any files needed.

If needed: the postfix version 2.11.3

Please note: example.net is the replacement for my domain. It is valid, DNS is set up and valid TLS certificates are installed.

---

**CONFIGURATION FILES**

postfix: main.cf

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname, reject_invalid_helo_hostname, reject_unknown_helo_hostname, permit
smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unknown_client_hostname, reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_pipelining, reject_unauth_destination, reject_invalid_hostname, reject_non_fqdn_sender
#smtpd_relay_restrictions = reject_unknown_client_hostname,reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unknown_recipient_domain,reject_unauth_pipelining, permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination, reject_invalid_hostname, reject_non_fqdn_sender
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_sender_login_mismatch
smtpd_sender_login_maps = $virtual_mailbox_maps
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom

smtpd_tls_ask_ccert = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/crypto/mail.example.net.chained.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/crypto/mail.example.net.key
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
smtpd_tls_ciphers = high
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_security_level = encrypt
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s 

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

myhostname = example.net
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
#mydestination =  $mydomain, raspberrysyncserver, localhost.localdomain, localhost
mydestination = raspberrysyncserver, localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 192.168.2.0/24 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
#relay_domains = example.net

unknown_address_reject_code = 550
unknown_hostname_reject_code = 550
unknown_client_reject_code = 550

canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/canonical
home_mailbox = Maildir/
message_size_limit = 104857600
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
virtual_mailbox_domains = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual-mailbox-domains
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual-mailbox-users
virtual_transport = dovecot

dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1

default_destination_concurrency_limit = 5
disable_vrfy_command = yes
relay_destination_concurrency_limit = 1
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
#smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
smtp_dns_support_level = dnssec
smtp_tls_security_level = dane
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated,reject_unknown_client_hostname, reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_pipelining, reject_unauth_destination, reject_invalid_hostname, reject_non_fqdn_sender

milter_default_action = accept
milter_connect_macros = j {daemon_name} v {if_name} _
non_smtpd_milters = $smtpd_milters
#smtpd_milters = unix:/spamassassin/spamd.sock unix:/clamav/clamav-milter.ctl unix:/opendkim/opendkim.sock
smtpd_milters = unix:/clamav/clamav-milter.ctl unix:/opendkim/opendkim.sock
```

postfix: master.cf

```
#
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master").
#
# Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       1       postscreen
#smtpd     pass  -       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       -       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       -       -       0       tlsproxy
submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
#  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
#  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628       inet  n       -       -       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    fifo  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      fifo  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     fifo  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
#
# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
# agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
# and other message envelope options.
# ====================================================================
#
# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Recent Cyrus versions can use the existing "lmtp" master.cf entry.
#
# Specify in cyrus.conf:
#   lmtp    cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="localhost:lmtp" proto=tcp4
#
# Specify in main.cf one or more of the following:
#  mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#  virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
# Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
# Old example of delivery via Cyrus.
#
#old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=R user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -   n   n   -   2   pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}

dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/deliver
  -f ${sender} -d $(recipient)
```

mail.log (snippet)

```
May  3 16:29:09 raspberrysyncserver postfix/smtpd[30395]: Trusted TLS connection established from MyComputer[192.168.2.150]: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 (128/128 bits)
May  3 16:29:11 raspberrysyncserver postfix/smtpd[30395]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from MyComputer[192.168.2.150]: 554 5.7.1 <recipient@web.de>: Relay access denied; from=<sender@example.net> to=<recipient@web.de> proto=ESMTP helo=<[192.168.2.150]>
May  3 16:29:13 raspberrysyncserver postfix/smtpd[30395]: disconnect from MyComputer[192.168.2.150]
```

Comment: So, you are sending email to recipient@web.de. Is that supposed to be a local domain or are you trying to relay? btw. if you follow a guide, it's usually good practice to link it right away.

Comment: web.de is an actual e-mail provider on the internet. added the links to the guide. recipient@web.de isn't the actual adress but rather some valid adress from me from which I can send and receive

Comment: So local email is working fine. It just won't relay. That is quite strange. I'd try adding `debug_peer_list 192.168.2.150` to the config and see what happens in the log. IIRC with higher verbosity it should tell you why it was rejected.

Comment: @Fox, log's here: http://pastebin.com/eqhsxZBL, not sure how to insert it into my main post, as it's 50k characters+

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rejection was caused by `smtpd_recipient_restrictions`. Delete `reject_unauth_destination` from `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` should fix the problem.

You have already put `reject_unauth_destination` in `smtpd_relay_restrictions`, so no need to put it again in `smtpd_recipient_restrictions`.

Answer (score 3):

This is the tell-tale part of the log. Leads to masegaloeh's answer.

```
May  3 17:26:04 raspberrysyncserver postfix/smtpd[31303]: >>> START Recipient address RESTRICTIONS <<<
May  3 17:26:04 raspberrysyncserver postfix/smtpd[31303]: generic_checks: name=reject_unknown_client_hostname
May  3 17:26:04 raspberrysyncserver postfix/smtpd[31303]: reject_unknown_client: mycomputer 192.168.2.150
May  3 17:26:04 raspberrysyncserver postfix/smtpd[31303]: generic_checks: name=reject_unknown_client_hostname status=0
May  3 17:26:04 raspberrysyncserver postfix/smtpd[31303]: generic_checks: name=reject_unknown_sender_domain
May  3 17:26:04 raspberrysyncserver postfix/smtpd[31303]: reject_unknown_address: sender@mydomain.net
May  3 17:26:04 raspberrysyncserver postfix/smtpd[31303]: ctable_locate: leave existing entry key sender@mydomain.net
May  3 17:26:04 raspberrysyncserver postfix/smtpd[31303]: generic_checks: name=reject_unknown_sender_domain status=0
May  3 17:26:04 raspberrysyncserver postfix/smtpd[31303]: generic_checks: name=reject_unknown_recipient_domain
May  3 17:26:04 raspberrysyncserver postfix/smtpd[31303]: reject_unknown_address: recipient@web.de
May  3 17:26:04 raspberrysyncserver postfix/smtpd[31303]: ctable_locate: move existing entry key recipient@web.de
May  3 17:26:04 raspberrysyncserver postfix/smtpd[31303]: reject_unknown_mailhost: web.de
May  3 17:26:04 raspberrysyncserver postfix/smtpd[31303]: lookup web.de type MX flags 0
May  3 17:26:04 raspberrysyncserver postfix/smtpd[31303]: dns_query: web.de (MX): OK
May  3 17:26:04 raspberrysyncserver postfix/smtpd[31303]: dns_get_answer: type MX for web.de
May  3 17:26:04 raspberrysyncserver postfix/smtpd[31303]: dns_get_answer: type MX for web.de
May  3 17:26:04 raspberrysyncserver postfix/smtpd[31303]: generic_checks: name=reject_unknown_recipient_domain status=0
May  3 17:26:04 raspberrysyncserver postfix/smtpd[31303]: generic_checks: name=reject_unauth_pipelining
May  3 17:26:04 raspberrysyncserver postfix/smtpd[31303]: reject_unauth_pipelining: RCPT
May  3 17:26:04 raspberrysyncserver postfix/smtpd[31303]: generic_checks: name=reject_unauth_pipelining status=0
May  3 17:26:04 raspberrysyncserver postfix/smtpd[31303]: generic_checks: name=reject_unauth_destination
May  3 17:26:04 raspberrysyncserver postfix/smtpd[31303]: reject_unauth_destination: recipient@web.de
May  3 17:26:04 raspberrysyncserver postfix/smtpd[31303]: permit_auth_destination: recipient@web.de
May  3 17:26:04 raspberrysyncserver postfix/smtpd[31303]: ctable_locate: leave existing entry key recipient@web.de
May  3 17:26:04 raspberrysyncserver postfix/smtpd[31303]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mycomputer[192.168.2.150]: 554 5.7.1 <recipient@web.de>: Relay access denied; from=<sender@mydomain.net> to=<recipient@web.de> proto=ESMTP helo=<[192.168.2.150]>
May  3 17:26:04 raspberrysyncserver postfix/smtpd[31303]: generic_checks: name=reject_unauth_destination status=2
```

Comment: can't mark your answer as well "*the* answer", but many thanks for your help and analysis